# Linux computer (Debian) in a Windows Active Directory Domain, Administrator of AD should have root permission after login

Tags: linux, active-directory, debian, groups, winbind

I managed to join my Debian machine (Squeeze) to an existing Active Directory (MS Windows 2008 R2 Server). Everything works fine, I can login using accounts from the Active Directory (NTP, Kerberos, PAM, Samba, and Winbind are all configured and seem to be in good shape).

Question:
I want to map Active Directory groups to UNIX groups as follows

- Domain-Admins (RID 512) -> root (gid
  0)
- Domain-Users (RID 513) -> users
  (gid 100)

I would like to achieve two goals:

1. Directories and files created by any user (including automatically created home folders) should have gid=100

   At the moment gid=10000, the automatically gid taken by winbind, is taken)
2. Members of the Domain-Admins group should have root privilege after login (alternatively: be member of the wheel group)

   At the moment, members of the Domain-Admins group are neither member of gid=0 nor the wheel group (it is not existing on my Debian installation, but that is another issue).

To achieve these goals, I tried to set the following mappings

- net groupmap add ntgroup="Domänen-Admins" unixgroup=root rid=512 type=domain
- net groupmap add ntgroup="Domänen-Benutzer" unixgroup=users rid=513 type=domain

This approach was unsuccessful, neither providing the SID instead of the RID did help. For each approach, I made sure that the winbind cache was empty (net cache flush) and both samba and winbind services were restarted.

Any recommendations?
Your support is highly appreciated! (and I know that there are some Debian gurus out there who have solved such a scenario ;-) )

Regards, Wolfram

---

In addition some information requested by user syneticon-dj:

*SIDs are scambled*

```
root@S15:~# net getdomainsid
SID for local machine S15 is: S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbbbbb-ccccccccc
SID for domain ITSL is: S-1-5-21-dddddddddd-eeeeeeeeee-ffffffffff
root@S15:~# net groupmap add ntgroup="Domänen-Admins" unixgroup=root rid=512 type=domain
Successfully added group Domänen-Admins to the mapping db as a domain group
root@S15:~# net groupmap add ntgroup="Domänen-Benutzer" unixgroup=users rid=513 type=domain
Successfully added group Domänen-Benutzer to the mapping db as a domain group
root@S15:~# net groupmap list
Domänen-Admins (S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbbbbb-ccccccccc-512) -> root
Domänen-Benutzer (S-1-5-21-aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbbbbb-ccccccccc-513) -> users
```

For me, it appears that the wrong group accounts are mapped. I mean the mapped SIDs correspond to the local machine SID instead of the domain SID. Anyway, it does not work, i.e. goal #1 is not achieved.

I have not found any option that enforces choosing the domain SID. Hence, I cleared the groupmap and added the mapping with the group SIDs directly as follows:

```
root@S15:~# net groupmap add ntgroup="Domänen-Benutzer" unixgroup=users sid="S-1-5-21-dddddddddd-eeeeeeeeee-ffffffffff-513" type=domain
Successfully added group Domänen-Benutzer to the mapping db as a domain group
root@S15:~# net groupmap list
Domänen-Benutzer (S-1-5-21-dddddddddd-eeeeeeeeee-ffffffffff-513) -> users
```

This approach does not work, either, i.e. goal #1 is not achieved.

As requested, here are the excerpts from **smb.conf**:

```
[global]
    workgroup = ITSL
    realm = itsl.local
    security = ADS
    # This machine is a member server, hence no authentication and we leave the following line commented
    ; domain logons = yes

    idmap uid = 10000-20000
    idmap gid = 10000-20000
    template shell = /bin/bash

    ;   winbind enum groups = yes
    ;   winbind enum users = yes

    winbind use default domain = yes
```

As requested, here are the excerpts from **PAM config**:

*Debian Squeeze defaults, nothing changed by me.*

```
root@S15:/etc/pam.d# grep 'winbind' *
common-account:account   [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore] pam_winbind.so
common-auth:auth         [success=1 default=ignore]                       pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
common-password:password [success=1 default=ignore]                       pam_winbind.so use_authtok try_first_pass
common-session:session   optional                                         pam_winbind.so
common-session-noninteractive:session   optional                          pam_winbind.so
```

Regards, Wolfram

Comment: Just a though, instead of making domain admins root, why not simply setup sudo, and grant members of the domain admins group the permissions you want.

Comment: Also, do you really want to start with a GID of 100?  On Debian systems a GID of 100-999 is in the range reserved for service accounts.

Comment: Zoredache, you are right, GID < 1000 is reserved for system. It includes the pre-defined group users which has GID=100. I want the Domain-Users group (RID=513) mapping to exactly this unix group (GID=100). The idea about sudo could be an alternative option for goal #2, I agree.

Comment: what's the result of "net groupmap list" then? And could you post the relevant parts of smb.conf and your pam config?

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to map the `uid` to root, nor the `gid` this way.

If you to give the Administrators root privileges on the system, you could use sudo.
You could use the Windows Group for granting the sudo privileges (Domain-Admins).

Comment: This solution does not meet the specification :-(